# Files on Windows and Contiguous Sectors

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is there a way to guarantee that a file on Windows (using the NTFS file system) will use contiguous sectors on the hard disk? In other words, the first chunk of the file will be stored in a certain sector, the second chunk of the file will be stored in the next sector, and so on.

I should add that I want to be able to create this file programmatically, so I'd rather not just ask the user to defrag their harddrive after creating this file. If there is a way to programmatically defrag just the file that I create, then that would be OK too.

Comment: Can you update your post with the purpose of doing this?  I assume it's for performance, but trying to optimize a file's location on the disk seems a bit over the top to me.  If you clarify what you're trying to do maybe there is another approach we can offer that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx

and follow Mark's documentation of the defrag stuff:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897427.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know of no such guarantees.

But also keep in mind that NTFS "files" are comprised of multiple data streams. So you are actually looking for a way to guarantee that a **stream** is contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way to achieve that. You can only defragment the file after it's been written.